# Lattice representation: change of unit cell

Tags: visualization-software, vesta, special-quasirandom-structures

(I use [VESTA](https://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/download.html) to visualize supercells with the `VASP` `POSCAR` format.)

Consider the following cell which has haunted me:

```
POSCAR
3.5668661195641991
  1.00000000 -1.00000000 -1.00000000
  1.00000000  1.00000000 -1.00000000
  1.50000000  0.00000000  2.50000000
   A  B
   8  24
Direct
  1.00000000  1.00000000  1.00000000
  0.06250000  0.06250000  0.25000000
  0.65625000  0.15625000  0.12500000
  0.71875000  0.21875000  0.37500000
  0.81250000  0.81250000  0.25000000
  0.15625000  0.65625000  0.12500000
  0.21875000  0.71875000  0.37500000
  0.93750000  0.93750000  0.75000000
  0.12500000  0.12500000  0.50000000
  0.53125000  0.03125000  0.62500000
  0.18750000  0.18750000  0.75000000
  0.59375000  0.09375000  0.87500000
  0.25000000  0.25000000  1.00000000
  0.31250000  0.31250000  0.25000000
  0.37500000  0.37500000  0.50000000
  0.03125000  0.53125000  0.62500000
  0.78125000  0.28125000  0.62500000
  0.43750000  0.43750000  0.75000000
  0.09375000  0.59375000  0.87500000
  0.84375000  0.34375000  0.87500000
  0.90625000  0.40625000  0.12500000
  0.56250000  0.56250000  0.25000000
  0.96875000  0.46875000  0.37500000
  0.62500000  0.62500000  0.50000000
  0.28125000  0.78125000  0.62500000
  0.68750000  0.68750000  0.75000000
  0.34375000  0.84375000  0.87500000
  0.75000000  0.75000000  1.00000000
  0.40625000  0.90625000  0.12500000
  0.50000000  0.50000000  1.00000000
  0.46875000  0.96875000  0.37500000
  0.87500000  0.87500000  0.50000000
```

I wish to rotate (or transform) this cell so that its non-orthogonal lattice vectors become orthogonal. I'm not sure anymore if this can be done.

Required lattice vectors (though, not a 100 % confident if this is what I need):

```
a` = 1.0 -1.0  0.0
b` = 1.0  1.0 -2.5
c` = 2.5  2.5  2.0
```

Original intent: This is a random FCC solid solution (SQS). I want to change the cell so that it looks like a usual FCC supercell.

Comment: I can't give an answer, but I don't think there is anything wrong with a non-orthogonal supercell.  I might recommend always using the Niggli representation of the cell as it makes it easy for others to generate the exact same cell.

Comment: I just gave an answer, but then deleted it because I think I misunderstood. Are you hoping to keep the same number of atoms, just reorganized into an orthogonal cell?

Comment: @wcw yes, the same # of atoms but an orthogonal traditional FCC like cell.

Comment: @wcw You should undelete your post, it is good information.  It is likely the best that can be done with this cell from my attempts.

Comment: Okay, I brought it back. The original question might have an answer, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will start by re-stating your question to make sure I understand what you mean. You have a cell with lattice vectors written in Cartesian coordinates as follows:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{a}=\hat{\mathbf{x}}-\hat{\mathbf{y}}-\hat{\mathbf{z}} \\
\mathbf{b}=\hat{\mathbf{x}}+\hat{\mathbf{y}}-\hat{\mathbf{z}} \\
\mathbf{c}=1.5\hat{\mathbf{x}}+2.5\hat{\mathbf{z}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
You then seek a transformation of this cell to obtain a new cell with the following lattice vectors:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{a}^{\prime}=\hat{\mathbf{x}}-\hat{\mathbf{y}} \\
\mathbf{b}^{\prime}=\hat{\mathbf{x}}+\hat{\mathbf{y}}-2.5\hat{\mathbf{z}} \\
\mathbf{c}^{\prime}=2.5\hat{\mathbf{x}}+2.5\hat{\mathbf{y}}+2\hat{\mathbf{z}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
A superlattice is related to an original lattice by a transformation matrix $S$ whose matrix elements $S_{ij}$ are *integers*. The relation is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{a}^{\prime} \\
\mathbf{b}^{\prime} \\
\mathbf{c}^{\prime}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
S_{11} & S_{12} & S_{13} \\
S_{21} & S_{22} & S_{23} \\
S_{31} & S_{32} & S_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{a} \\
\mathbf{b} \\
\mathbf{c}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So your question is: can we find a matrix $S$ of integer elements that obeys this equation? I think the answer is *no*.

This is most easily seen with the $\mathbf{c}^{\prime}$ lattice vector:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{c}^{\prime}&=&S_{31}\mathbf{a}+S_{32}\mathbf{b}+S_{33}\mathbf{c} \\
&=&S_{31}(\hat{\mathbf{x}}-\hat{\mathbf{y}}-\hat{\mathbf{z}})+S_{32}(\hat{\mathbf{x}}+\hat{\mathbf{y}}-\hat{\mathbf{z}})+S_{33}(1.5\hat{\mathbf{x}}+2.5\hat{\mathbf{z}}) \\
&=&(S_{31}+S_{32}+1.5S_{33})\hat{\mathbf{x}}+(-S_{31}+S_{32})\hat{\mathbf{y}}+(-S_{31}-S_{32}+2.5S_{33})\hat{\mathbf{z}}.
\end{eqnarray}
You want this to equal:
$$
\mathbf{c}^{\prime}=2.5\hat{\mathbf{x}}+2.5\hat{\mathbf{y}}+2\hat{\mathbf{z}}.
$$
If you compare the $\hat{\mathbf{y}}$ components, your condition becomes:
$$
-S_{31}+S_{32}=2.5.
$$
This equation has no solution for integer $S_{ij}$, so you cannot build the second set of cell parameters from the first.

[Disclaimer: plenty of signs and numbers, so may have a mistake in the calculation. However, you should still be able to use this strategy to figure out the correct answer if different.]

Comment: Thank you, ProfM. Perhaps, a simple solution to get orthogonal lattice vectors is orthogonalisation of these vectors. Though, I'm not sure if those would be valid lattice vectors. @wcw's answer seems to corroborate this doubt.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania if I understand you correctly, you are asking a different question now. You now want to build a supercell of your original cell in which the three lattice vectors are orthogonal (and presumably the smallest possible such supercell)? If so, you still have to solve the same set of equations I have in my answer with an *integer* supercell matrix, but now imposing the condition of orthogonality on the final set of lattice vectors. Simply orthogonalising is not enough if the transformation introduces non-integer linear combinations.

Comment: Ah, understood. That's why I was stuck. I tried Gram Schmidt orthonormalisation and tried to find the transformation matrix, which yielded fractional entries. I get it now. For any (non-physical meaning attached) set of vectors, the constraint of integer entries in the transformation matrix wouldn't hold, I suppose. In our case, because we want the transformed vectors to be lattice vectors as well, we impose the integer entries constraint. I hope I'm right?

Comment: The matrix $S = \begin{pmatrix} -3  & 1 &  0 \\ 1 & 1 & 4 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ gets you orthogonal lattice vectors, I think. Not sure if it's the smallest supercell.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania I think I agree with your latest comment. wcw, thanks for the matrix, not sure if it is the smallest either. Either way, the size of the supercell that a given transformation matrix gives is the determinant of the matrix.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania, is it safe to say ProfM has answered your question, or are you hoping for more still?

Comment: @wcw, yes, I think both of your answers together answer the question. I was just unsure which to approve as final. Since you've given the transformation matrix here in the comments, should I select this one?

Comment: @HitanshuSachania great! I think this one is definitely more useful

Answer (score 6):

I used the structure manipulation scripts provided by [AIRSS](https://www.mtg.msm.cam.ac.uk/Codes/AIRSS) to generate the conventional cell associated with your primitive cell. I think AIRSS uses [Spglib](https://spglib.github.io/spglib/) under the hood for this task, so you could probably use Spglib directly if you wanted.

**Original cell**

[image]

**New cell**

[image]

**POSCAR file**

```
POSCAR
1.0000000000000000     
10.0886200000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000
0.0000000000   7.1337300000   0.0000000000
-2.5221540330   0.0000000000  10.0886187273
A         B         
16        48
Direct
0.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000
0.4375000000   0.5000000000   0.7500000000
0.0937500000   0.2500000000   0.8750000000
0.0312500000   0.2500000000   0.6250000000
0.6875000000   0.5000000000   0.7500000000
0.0937500000   0.7500000000   0.8750000000
0.0312500000   0.7500000000   0.6250000000
0.5625000000   0.5000000000   0.2500000000
0.5000000000   0.5000000000   0.0000000000
0.9375000000   0.0000000000   0.7500000000
0.5937500000   0.7500000000   0.8750000000
0.5312500000   0.7500000000   0.6250000000
0.1875000000   0.0000000000   0.7500000000
0.5937500000   0.2500000000   0.8750000000
0.5312500000   0.2500000000   0.6250000000
0.0625000000   0.0000000000   0.2500000000
0.3750000000   0.5000000000   0.5000000000
0.2187500000   0.2500000000   0.3750000000
0.3125000000   0.5000000000   0.2500000000
0.1562500000   0.2500000000   0.1250000000
0.2500000000   0.5000000000   0.0000000000
0.1875000000   0.5000000000   0.7500000000
0.1250000000   0.5000000000   0.5000000000
0.2187500000   0.7500000000   0.3750000000
0.9687500000   0.2500000000   0.3750000000
0.0625000000   0.5000000000   0.2500000000
0.1562500000   0.7500000000   0.1250000000
0.9062500000   0.2500000000   0.1250000000
0.8437500000   0.2500000000   0.8750000000
0.9375000000   0.5000000000   0.7500000000
0.7812500000   0.2500000000   0.6250000000
0.8750000000   0.5000000000   0.5000000000
0.9687500000   0.7500000000   0.3750000000
0.8125000000   0.5000000000   0.2500000000
0.9062500000   0.7500000000   0.1250000000
0.7500000000   0.5000000000   0.0000000000
0.8437500000   0.7500000000   0.8750000000
-0.0000000000   0.5000000000   0.0000000000
0.7812500000   0.7500000000   0.6250000000
0.6250000000   0.5000000000   0.5000000000
0.8750000000   0.0000000000   0.5000000000
0.7187500000   0.7500000000   0.3750000000
0.8125000000   0.0000000000   0.2500000000
0.6562500000   0.7500000000   0.1250000000
0.7500000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000
0.6875000000   0.0000000000   0.7500000000
0.6250000000   0.0000000000   0.5000000000
0.7187500000   0.2500000000   0.3750000000
0.4687500000   0.7500000000   0.3750000000
0.5625000000   0.0000000000   0.2500000000
0.6562500000   0.2500000000   0.1250000000
0.4062500000   0.7500000000   0.1250000000
0.3437500000   0.7500000000   0.8750000000
0.4375000000   0.0000000000   0.7500000000
0.2812500000   0.7500000000   0.6250000000
0.3750000000   0.0000000000   0.5000000000
0.4687500000   0.2500000000   0.3750000000
0.3125000000   0.0000000000   0.2500000000
0.4062500000   0.2500000000   0.1250000000
0.2500000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000
0.3437500000   0.2500000000   0.8750000000
0.5000000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000
0.2812500000   0.2500000000   0.6250000000
0.1250000000   0.0000000000   0.5000000000
```

I realize this isn't exactly what you wanted (e.g., the new cell vectors aren't actually orthogonal), but I am leaving it here because of the comments requesting for me to undelete the answer.